# Securing Data Via Fingerprint Verification

Tags: android, ios

I'm looking into ways to secure data on mobile via fingerprint verification.

The situtation on iOS seems fairly straight-forward by securing data in the Keychain via Touch.

But can something like this be done on Android where a piece of data is secured via a fingerprint? Or would we have to handle the association of data and fingerprint internally within the app?

**UPDATE:**

So having done a little bit more reading on this on Android I'm assuming the best way of doing this would be to encrypt the data within the app but secure the key being used with FingerprintManager and the Android Keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're heading into the right direction ;-)

Basically the Keystore is just for creating / storing key material and cannot be compared to something like the SharedPreferences. You could use the Keystore APIs to create a new cryptographic key which requires user authentication and with the generated key you could then en-/decrypt data. In order to access the key inside the Keystore the user needs to authenticate (e.g. through fingerprint authentication).

I have created a demo project for the new Keystore APIs (including fingerprint authentication) which you can find on GitHub: https://github.com/flschweiger/SafeApp